# Analytical solution for optimization with inequality constraints

Tags: optimization

Let the following be known matrices with dimensions as:

$M = nXk$, all elements >0

$w_b = 1Xn$, all elements >0 , sums to 1

$S = nXn$, a positive semidefinite matrix

$C_c = 1Xk$, all elements >0

$C_b = 1Xn$, all elements >0

$1_k = 1Xk$ vector of 1's

I need to solve for $w_c = 1Xk$ in the following:

$Min_{w_c}( (w_cM' - w_b) S(w_cM' - w_b)')$  such that $1_kw_c'  = 1 $ , and $C_cw_c'  = C_b w_b'$ , and $w_c >= 0 $ (all elements of $w_c $ >=0)

I can solve with only the equality constraints with lagrange multipliers

Obj:
$ (w_cM' - w_b) S(w_cM' - w_b)' - \lambda_1 (1_kw_c'  - 1) - \lambda_2(C_cw_c'  - C_b w_b')$

However, I am not sure how to solve with the third constraint, i.e. $w_c >= 0 $. Can this problem be solved analytically? Or do I have to use some numerical routine?

Comment: is $w_c >= 0$ a element-wise inequality?

Comment: @NikosM. yes it is

Comment: in scalar optimisation with inequalities one introduces *slack variables* which help to transform the inequalities into equality constratints which are then handled with lagrange multipliers, eg http://users.wpi.edu/~pwdavis/Courses/MA1024B10/1024_Lagrange_multipliers.pdf

Comment: @NikosM. yes i thought of that, but here, it seems like for each element of wc, it will give a choice between making that element 0, or making the lagrange multiplier 0. Not sure how to go about that.

Comment: take a look at [non-negative least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) which uses quadratic programming to solve.

Comment: according to [this math.se post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543311/analytical-solution-of-constrained-linear-least-squares-problems-with-bounds-x-%E2%89%A4) and quite a search, there seems to be no closed-form analytic solution to this problem (which can be seen as variation of non-negative least squares problem)

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks for that. I've been trying to using scipy for this but it is failing. Let me put more details

Comment: `scipy` has [`scipy.optimize.nnls`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) method to solve non-negative least squares

Comment: @NikosM. Doesnt look like this is nnls though since there is another constraint (equality constraint)

Comment: Of course, but can be seen as a variation on nnls and maybe you can find a more general algorithm available or even adapt an algorithm from nnls to your problem